# In 2020, how does one sync a NSPersistentDocument based app across devices (macOS, iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, cloud, nspersistentdocument

Suppose a macOS application using NSPersistentDocument (thus CoreData). All user data is stored in `<documentName>.<myApp>` files.
In 2020, if I were to develop an iOS version of the application, how could I provide the functionality to the users to sync these documents between macOS and iOS?

From my research, it looks like using CloudKit is not the way to go for a NSDocument-based app.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006882/are-nspersistentdocument-and-uimanageddocument-compatible

Comment: You can use `UIManagedDocument` on iOS, and on macOS some additional coordination logic will have to be implemented. Or, switch to Catalyst, and use `UIManagedDocument` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks guys. Shouldn't Apple provided documentation about this? I cannot believe this use case is so exotic.